# How do I set a header when overriding the SessionsController#create action of Devise controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I wrote a small method to generate a JWT and save it on the user model. I'm now trying to override the SessionsController#create method to send back the token on successful login. This is how I'm attempting to do it:

```
    # SessionsController#create
    def create
        super do |user|
            if user.persisted?
                user.generate_auth_token!
                response.set_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + user.auth_token)
            end
        end
    end
```

```
    # user model
    def generate_auth_token!
        payload = { user_id: self.id }
        token = JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base, 'HS256')
        self.auth_token = token
        self.auth_token_expiration = DateTime.now + 30.days
        self.save!
    end
```

The token is generated just fine, and it appears to be saved on the user model when I inspect the user record via the rails console.

I'm using Postman (it's like cURL, but with a nice GUI) to inspect the headers from logging in, and there is no 'Authorization' header.

Comment: Your response may be overridden by the next line [`respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/98fc5e8e396b66b826528811287ea6680a6d0757/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L23). So you may need to override the entire method unfortunately unless you can find some clue in the [responders gem docs](https://github.com/heartcombo/responders) on how to customize the response.

Comment: You could also potentially override the `respond_with` method but that feels almost as hacky as copy pasting the entire  `create` method.

Comment: Seems the issue is that there's a 302 redirect, which Postman follows. Apparently the Authorization header is lost then when the 302 is followed by Postman.

Comment: The redirect is almost certainly caused by `respond_with` setting the location header and status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do like this `response.headers['your_header_name'] = 'value'`

Comment: I tried that as well, doesn't seem to show up in the output in Postman. Do I need to explicitly expose this header maybe?

Comment: what do u mean by explicitly expose?

Comment: https://glaucocustodio.github.io/2016/01/20/dont-forget-to-expose-headers-when-using-rack-cors/

Comment: put the response after do end block, maybe it helps

Comment: Also your controller should be inherited from Devise::SessionsController

Comment: ok lol, it's this dumb GUI client apparently, for some unknown reason I can't see the authorization header in Postman, but when I use a plain old cURL command I see it...... jeez

Comment: this is technically the right answer... but I was experiencing some other problem before I could get this to work.